# How to declare table type inside structure?

Tags: abap

In order to achieve my smartform, I'm supposed to declare a table within a structure. I tried this but it's not working:

```
TYPES: t_qase2 TYPE TABLE OF qase.

TYPES: 
BEGIN OF ty_itab.
  pruefer type qase-pruefer.
  zeiterstl type qase-zeiterstl.
*  ......(other fields)
  ty_qase2 type t_qase2.
  INCLUDE STRUCTURE s_f800komp.
TYPES END OF ty_itab.
```

Comment: In order to include a table as part of a structure, the table has to be FULLY specified, including the key. 

It is actually recommended to use WITH EMPTY key in stead of WITH DEFAULT key, but I'm not sure at what patch level the EMPTY keyword becomes available.  Both will work, but if you don't want to define a key EMPTY is more accurate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To declare a table in a structure you simply give a table type with non-unique key to one of the fields:

```
TYPES: myTableType TYPE TABLE OF string WITH NON-UNIQUE DEFAULT KEY.

TYPES: BEGIN OF ty_itab,
    pruefer    type qase-pruefer,
    zeiterstl  type qase-zeiterstl,
    myTable    type myTableType, "Table is here
    ty_qase2   type t_qase2.
    INCLUDE STRUCTURE s_f800komp.
TYPES:  END OF ty_itab.
```

Also notice that you end every line with a dot. In this case you have to use `,`

Comment: This is the most common misconception. And even I struggle sometimes, when not used for quite a while, that's why Your answer is bookmarked for me :-) .

Answer (score 1):

Besides the variant proposed by previous answerer, there is variant of table declaration inside structure in an explicit way:

```
TYPES: BEGIN OF ty_itab,
  pruefer    TYPE qase-pruefer,
  zeiterstl  TYPE qase-zeiterstl,
  myTable    TYPE TABLE OF string WITH NON-UNIQUE DEFAULT KEY,
  ty_qase2   TYPE t_qase2.
  INCLUDE STRUCTURE s_f800komp.
TYPES:  END OF ty_itab.
```